# Laravel livewire tags are not interpreted

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-10

I have a Laravel project where I normally work between laptop and pc. These days, I installed livewire and make some components, all works fine. I uploaded my code to git and download in my desktop pc, but this pc doest interpret the livewire tags:

```
<main>
    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8 space-y-6">

            <div class="p-4 sm:p-8 bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 shadow sm:rounded-lg">
                <section class="text-gray-600 body-font">
                    <livewire:list-shops>
                </livewire:list-shops></section>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

I installed livewire in my desktop pc:

`composer require livewire/livewire`

and clear caches with:

`php artisan cache:clear`

I stopped and started again vite and artisan. What more I need to make this work? Some cache problem? I want this livewire tags in the blade template work again.

Comment: livewire3, I just change the image for the raw code, thanks